How to use DMA in Linux to talk to an old PCI card
I have a very old PCI card that contains DPRAM. Linux is supposed to map the DPRAM such that it can be accessed via DMA. I keep finding articles that get me one step further in this process, but I can't find anything that gives an end to end solution for recent kernel versions.
The process so far is roughly:

Find the device address using lspci (ex. 04:0e.0)
Query /proc/iomem to get the memory address of the device from the previous step
Use this code to attempt to get a memory mapped location for DMA

int file = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
int addr_from_proc_iomem = 0xb1400000;
void* data = mmap(nullptr, data_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, file, addr_from_proc_iomem );

Using separate software that accesses the PCI card via a serial cable I can see that the card is updating memory that should be seen in the memory mapped area, but when I read the mapped memory I see only zeros.
Does anyone know of a complete Linux driver example that does what I'm trying to do (read DPRAM via DMA in Linux)? Or do you have pointers on the steps I'm missing. I'm using Debian with a 6.1 kernel.
